# Is there a way to clip an image in an image container div?

Tags: css, image

How can I clip an image contained in an image container div? 
I tried `overflow-y:hidden` for the image and image container?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details like your html, css code and a jsfiddle if possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change the container dimensions. Then use absolute positioning to change the position of the image.

```
<div class=container> //position:relative
<img src="example.png" /> //position:absolute
</div>
```